# Hyperledger - Building Your First Network error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am getting the below error while trying to bring up the network (fabric_samples)

Error: got unexpected status: FORBIDDEN -- Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining: permission denied

Comment: bring more details of what are you doing and from where this error comes from

Answer (score 1):

You can try this command to clear the network previously configured, it worked for me.

```
./byfn.sh -m down
```